# Display down arrow inside a span class in html just like a plus in the code displays?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, nav

I am wondering since the class "fa fa-plus"
displays the + sign in the navigation bar dropdown menu, how I would display the down arrow? Here is my current HTML:

```
  <span class="fa fa-dropdown"></span>
```

I am using [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
```

I got the HTML from the site, where you can search for all the icons. Here is the link:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/caret-down?style=solid

Comment: Some additional thoughts. 1) Using the i tag instead of span is common. Think i is for image. 2) Font awesome has moved from `fa` to `fas` for the default library. `fa` current works but they may remove it in the future.